# Fußnoten hinter Zahlen

Tags: mathematics, typography

Fußnoten lassen sich mit hochgestellten Zahlen definieren, wie z.B. »hallo¹«. Ich brauche die Fußnote aber für einen mathematischen Inhalt. Zum Beispiel brauche ich die Fußnote nicht für *hallo,* sondern für die Zahl 50. Und »50¹« könnte missverstanden werden. Wie benutzt man also Fußnoten für Zahlen?

Comment: Innerhalb eines mathematischen Terms kann man keine Fußnoten anbringen. Wenn es sich um Fließtext handelt und eine Fußnote nötig ist, kommt der Verweis auf die Fußnote eben ans Ende des Satzes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wenn es nicht irgendeinen zwingenden Grund gibt, Fußnoten durchzunummerieren, würde ich Symbole statt Zahlen als Fußnotenzeichen verwenden, idealerweise welche, die Du nicht für andere Zwecke wie mathematische Formeln verwendest.

Die Klassiker für die ersten Fußnoten sind *, <sup>†</sup> und <sup>‡</sup>. Vor allem der Asterisk (*) hat den Vorteil, dass er in dieser Verwendung weit verbreitet ist, und somit die meisten Leser als erstes eine Fußnote statt irgendeiner speziellen Notation vermuten. Das Kreuz (†) hingegen kann auch anzeigen, dass jemand verstorben ist, was für einige Texte kein Problem darstellt. Alle drei Symbole werden auch als mathematische Notation verwendet, und sind deshalb auch nicht unbedingt die beste Wahl für entsprechende Texte.

In Zeiten von Unicode ist es jedoch technisch kein Problem, exotischere Symbole zu verwenden, sofern die Schriftart der Wahl diese unterstützt. Zum Beispiel habe ich für meine Dissertation *, ˤ, ʵ und ʶ als Fußnotensymbole verwendet. Dies hat allerdings den Nachteil, dass es Leser verwirren kann, wenn sie hinter dem Symbol erstmal keine Fußnote vermuten.

So oder so rate ich davon ab, Fußnoten *innerhalb* mathematischer Formeln (statt dahinter) zu verwenden, da sie hier zu sehr Gefahr laufen als mathematische Notation verstanden zu werden.

Comment: Alles klar. Das hilft mir schonmal sehr viel. Dankeschön!

Comment: Noten habe ich auch schon gesehen. Wenn mehrere auf der gleichen Seite nötig sind eine Note, zwei Noten usw. Bei mehr als 5 Noten wird es aber lästig. :) Gibt es ein UTF-Zeichen für Fuß?

Comment: Aber sicher:       Den Skin-Tone-Modifier, und damit implizit die Farbe, für Fußnotenunterscheidung zu verwenden wäre mal was neues :)

Answer (score 5):

Ich bin es gewohnt, meine Fußnoten in eckige Klammern einzuschließen.<sup>[1]</sup> Es ist zwar trotzdem möglich, dass in einem speziellen Untergebiet der Mathematik eine hochgestellte Zahl in eckigen Klammern eine Bedeutung hat, aber es ist wesentlich weniger einladend als 50<sup>1[2]</sup> – für die meisten Leser.

Innerhalb einer komplexen Formel verbieten sich Fußnoten meines Erachtens ohnehin. Wenn es darum geht, einen bestimmten Wert zu belegen, ist es oft möglich, in die Formel eine Variable einzusetzen und an anderer Stelle (zum Beispiel im Fließtext) die Variable mit dem Wert gleichzusetzen und *das* dann mit Fußnote zu belegen.

Zum Beispiel würde ich von Folgendem abraten:

> *E* = 100 kg × 90.000.000.000 km<sup>2</sup> s<sup>−2[3]</sup>

Und stattdessen vorschlagen:

> *E* = 100 × *c*<sup>2</sup>
>
> Wobei *c* = 300.000 km s<sup>−1</sup> die Lichtgeschwindigkeit darstellt.<sup>[3]</sup>

Mein Beispiel ist natürlich sehr aus den Fingern gezogen, aber Umformulieren oder Umstellen ist immer möglich.

In anderen Fällen kann einem auch Kreativität weiterhelfen. Wenn ich zum Beispiel eine Liste mit Siedepunkten für verschiedene Lösungsmittel habe, muss ich die Fußnote nicht am Wert selbst anbringen, sondern könnte sie auch am Lösungsmittel anbringen, wo weniger Missverständnisse auftreten können.

[1]: Ja, genau so.

[2]: Jedes Beispiel kann beliebig kompliziert gestaltet werden, sodass jede Möglichkeit irgendwann zu scheitern droht, wie hier.

[3]: Weiß jeder, muss ich eigentlich nicht zitieren.